# C# : Populate Combobox based on Another

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Ok don't chastise me until you fully read this.  I know how to populate a combobox based on the selectedindex of another combobox, and have tested the method I found and it works.

I'm building an application for work and am trying to do a lot more than my test build so if this is a simple fix forgive me...  just learned C# like 3 weeks ago and have only made 1 application so far and it was very crude.

So to my problem....  I'm using SqlCE to store basic data for my forms.

I have a BaseForm that stores variables and methods common to all of my forms.  Within this BaseForm I have all of my SqlCE content setup and ready for use with all of my sub-forms.
They are setup as such:

```
internal SqlCeConnection dataConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\opi_data.sdf");
internal SqlCeCommand command;
internal SqlCeDataReader drDataSet;

internal void openDataConnection() // Opens a connection to the data tables 
        {
            try
            {
                if(dataConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    dataConn.Open();
            }
            catch(SqlCeException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is populate two comboboxes, the first or parent box is a Bind Type, this stores the types of Binds that we carry.  It is setup as such:
In the BaseForm:

```
internal void populateComboBox(string boxCommand, string itemsAdding, ComboBox comboBox) // Auto populates a combo box 
{
    comboBox.Items.Clear();
    openDataConnection();
    try
    {
        command = new SqlCeCommand(boxCommand, dataConn);

        drDataSet = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (drDataSet.Read())
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(drDataSet[itemsAdding].ToString());
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataConn.Close();
    }
}

internal void populateComboBox(string boxCommand, string itemsAdding, int typeSelector, ComboBox comboBox) // Auto populate a combo box based on another 
{
    comboBox.Items.Clear();
    openDataConnection();
    try
    {
        command = new SqlCeCommand(boxCommand + " WHERE TypeID = @type ORDER BY Id", dataConn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", typeSelector);

        drDataSet = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (drDataSet.Read())
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(drDataSet[itemsAdding].ToString());
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataConn.Close();
    }
}
```

As you can see these are two overloaded methods.  The first is used to populate the parent combobox and the second is used to populate and filter the child combobox.

Now in my form I have setup the comboboxes to populate as soon as the form is consturcted:

```
public partial class JobLog : BaseForm
{
        public JobLog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            jobLogSetup();
        }
        private void jobLogSetup() // Initially sets up the form for use 
        {
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindtypes ORDER BY Id", "Type", comboBox3); // Populate bind type combo box
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 1, comboBox4); // Populate bind size combo box
        }
}
```

The bind type (parent) combobox is comboBox3 and the bind size (child) combobox is comboBox4.

This works beautifully...  As I have to use the same methods for other sets of comboboxes as well.  So to my problem:  The methods work perfectly, no matter where I call them they always update the comboboxes... except when I try to call them using and if statement or switch statement in the combobox_SelectedIndexChanged event....

What I used previously and worked in my first application was a switch and thus I mimicked it here:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox3.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 1, comboBox4);
            break;
        case 1:
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 2, comboBox4);
            break;
        case 2:
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 3, comboBox4);
            break;
        case 3:
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 4, comboBox4);
            break;
        case 4:
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 5, comboBox4);
            break;
        case 5:
            populateComboBox("SELECT * FROM bindsizes", "Size", 6, comboBox4);
            break;
    }
}
```

However, when I use it in my newer application, I always get an error stating : "Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed" as soon as I hit debug...  then I click OK and the form loads, only neither parent nor child combobox has been populated.  But if I don't use the switch or if statements and just set it some other way, I can populate them, but I can't get the child combobox to populate based on the parent comboboxes selection....

I have toyed with this for the past 4 hours and quite frankly my brain is fried, so I moved on to another part of the application....  Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: As the error suggests, your connection is closed.  In fact, you are opening then closing it, opening then closing it ad nauseum.

Comment: Remove comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0; from the populateComboBox() method with three variables. It's casuing your indexchanged event to fire.

Comment: @ Brian >> So your saying I should leave the connection open 24/7?  The connections stay open so long as they are neeeded, otherwise there's no reason to have them open.  And they are only opened and closed twice in this example....

@ KreepN >> Problem, I need the parent and child combo boxes to be set by default to the first index in the list from the beginning....  Also it didn't create an issue in my original application, why would it now?

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it.... just needed to switch where the selected index was being called....

Comment: @JoshC. Like I said :). If you plan on sticking around the site, we do have a rep system that people get credit for if we answered your problem. I'd submit my answer if you plan on coming back, let me know.